# Arrow Key Press detected at ANY POINT

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I've done some search on how key press detection works with c++, and I have a key detection program that checks the **Down** and **Right arrow key**, which works fine. However I have another very simple input program, and I want to know if it's possible to be able to **detect an arrow key was pressed whilst the user is inputting somewhere else**, i.e in the `something1` variable for example.

Here's what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

#define KEY_RIGHT 77
#define KEY_DOWN 80

string something1, something2, something3;

bool loggedIn = false;
int value = 0;

void type() {
cout << "Type something: ";
cin >> something1;

cout << "Type something again: ";
cin >> something2;

cout << "Type something one more time: ";
cin >> something3;
}

int main()
{
type();

while (loggedIn == false)
{
    value = 0;

    switch ((value = _getch())) {
        break;
    case KEY_DOWN:
        cout << "You pressed the Down Arrow Key" << endl;
        break;
    case KEY_RIGHT:
        cout << "You pressed the Right Arrow Key" << endl;
        break;
    }

}
}
```

The `type()` function asks the user for 3 strings, so we don't hit the while loop until all 3 string prompts have been passed. But is there a way to somehow merge these 2 blocks of code together so that whilst the user is typing into variable `something1` for example, and hits the **Down Arrow**, they are thrown the message in the `KEY_DOWN` case?

I'm not sure if this sort of thing is possible, but I thought it's worth a shot asking.

Comment: `cin >> stringvar` will not return until an end of line is entered, so there's no way to break in the middle of it for an arrow key. You could do it with a windowed input but that's far beyond the scope of a simple answer.

Comment: *I've done some search on how key press detection works with c++* -- The C++ language knows nothing about key press detection.  That is an operating system specific item.

Comment: You need a keyboard hook for this. Look at `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `RegisterRawInputDevices()` to receive keystroke events from the OS before they reach `cin` (or any other app).

Answer (score 0):

As @Remy Lebeau said that , you can use [SetWindowsHookEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) to detect arrow key.

Here is sample:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#pragma comment( lib, "user32.lib" )

#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

HHOOK hKeyboardHook;
string something1;
string something2;
string something3;

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardEvent(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD SHIFT_key = 0;
    DWORD CTRL_key = 0;
    DWORD ALT_key = 0;


    if ((nCode == HC_ACTION) && ((wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) || (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)))
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hooked_key = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        DWORD dwMsg = 1;
        dwMsg += hooked_key.scanCode << 16;
        dwMsg += hooked_key.flags << 24;
        int key = hooked_key.vkCode;
        if (key == 40)
        {
            cout << "You pressed the Down Arrow Key" << endl;
        }   

    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void MessageLoop()
{
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI my_HotKey(LPVOID lpParm)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (!hInstance) hInstance = LoadLibrary((LPCSTR)lpParm);
    if (!hInstance) return 1;

    hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)KeyboardEvent, hInstance, NULL);
    MessageLoop();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwThread; 
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD mode = 0;

    GetConsoleMode(out, &mode);
    SetConsoleMode(out, mode &~ENABLE_LINE_INPUT);

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)my_HotKey, (LPVOID)argv[0], NULL, &dwThread);

    std::cout << "Type something: " << endl;
    cin >> something1 ;
    std::cout << "Type something again: " << endl;
    cin >> something2;
    std::cout << "Type something one more time: " << endl;
    cin >> something3;

    /* uncomment to hide console window */
 //ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);
    //Used for test:
    std::cout<< "----" << something1;
    std::cout << "-------" << something2;
    std::cout << "----------" << something3;
    if (hThread) return WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    else return 1;

}
```

Debug:

[image]

If you don't know how to use the hook, then please refer to the official documentation.

Link: [Using Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-hooks)

You need to create another thread to place the `MessageLoop`, because both `MessageLoop` and `cin` input stream have blocking mechanisms..

**Note: Because of the caching mechanism of the console itself, for some of the effects of the arrow keys, such as typing characters, pressing the up arrow will clear the characters. Please try it yourself.**